# Not able to use Windows Script Host Object Model in .net 3.5 project

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# console application (.Net version 3.5) with following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork aNetworkInstance = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork();
}
```

When I run the program it is throwing following error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is
>   built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot
>   be loaded.

I found that the generated interop file Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll is refering to 4.0.0.0 version of mscorelib.

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

If I change the .net version of the project to 4, then it is working fine. Any idea why the Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll is always refering to version 4 of mscorlib even when I select .net 3.5 in the project?

PS: The same program is working in other systems. The issue is only in one system.

> EDIT: Following are the steps I have done.

Create a C# Console application (.Net version 3.5).
Add referece to Windows Scribt Host Object model

Add following line in the Main()

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork aNetworkInstance = new IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshNetwork();
}
```

When I run the application, it is throwing following exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is
>   built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot
>   be loaded.

I am able to build and run the project in other machines.
If I copy the Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll generated in another machine, then also the program is running in my machine.
But I am not able to run the program with the Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll generated in my machine.

I know it is a strange problem. May be I have to reformat my hard disk as you suggested by Hans Passant :(

> EDIT: Output of the detailed build

```
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\TlbImp.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wshom.ocx /namespace:IWshRuntimeLibrary /machine:X86 /out:obj\x86\Release\Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll /sysarray /transform:DispRet /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\stdole\7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\stdole.dll 
1>  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Type Library to Assembly Converter 4.0.30319.33440
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>  
1>  TlbImp : Type library imported to C:\Users\IC007121\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\wsherrortest\wsherrortest\obj\x86\Release\Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll
1>  Resolved COM reference for item "IWshRuntimeLibrary": "obj\x86\Release\Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll".
```

Comment: It's a problem related to 32bits/64bits compilation. It occurs when you're trying to load a library compiled in another flavor than your program.

Comment: I tried to build the project with x86, x64 and Any CPU platforms. Getting same error in all cases.

Comment: Ok. So, on other machines, is it referring mscorlib v4 ? because the messsage is explicit `This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.`.

Comment: In other machine Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll is referring to 2.0.0.0 version


.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}

Comment: That's the reason, on other machines it refers to the .Net 2.0 version of mscorlib while on your machine it's referring the .Net 4.0 version. You're stuck to use a .Net 4.0 project. And it's a bad idea to deploy your application with embedding the version you need => it's a part of Windows.

Comment: I don't want to stuck to .net version 4.0. All I need is to make my program working with Windows 7 (.Net 3.5). I don't know why in my machine always the geneated interop dll is referring to version 4.0 of mscorlib.

Comment: Windows 7 works well with .net 4.0 and if your machine have the v4 version of the lib, it's because the .Net 4.0 is installed on it. So what's the problem ?

Comment: Can you try to create a [yourexe].exe.config file with this inside: `<configuration><startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" /></startup></configuration>`

Comment: By default the version in the generated config file is v2.0.50727. If I change it to v4.0.30319, then the application is running. But I want application to work only with .net 3.5.

Comment: Could you share the project somewhere (including binaries)? I can't reproduce with Visutal Studio 2015

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce in any other machine. So I don't think sharing the project would help. Program contains just one line of code as explained in the question.

Comment: Can you go to your VS menu `Tools/Options/Project and Solutions/Build and Run`, and select `Detailed` for `MSbuild project build output verbosity`. Then do a full rebuild and check the output window for your project. Search for the output of the "ResolveComReference" task. You should see the command line for the TLBIMP.EXE SDK tool that's used undercover. This tools has a /reference argument that is set to the CLR (though mscorlib). Check that out, in your case it probably points to mscorlib 4.x. or may be it's a super old version of this tool or you just don't have FX 2 installed (I doubt).

Comment: Detailed for MSbuild project build output is added to the question.

Comment: is 4.0 or greater installed on the other machines ?

Comment: Yes. Visual studio 2013 is installed in all machines. In my machine, both visual studio 2013 and 2008 is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio uses a SDK tool named [TlbImp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx) to build COM references import files. The MsBuild task that does that is named [ResolveComReference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e00bfh.aspx). This task uses an algorithm that tries to find the proper TlbImp version on the machine that builds the project.

In your case as we see it from msbuild diagnostics, it uses the TlbImp from "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools`". Unfortunately, this TlbImp builds CLR 4 assemblies. So you need to use another TlbImp. On my machine, it uses it from "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin`" which builds CLR 2 assembly. You probably don't have that TlbImp installed on your build machine so the algorithm redirects silently to the newer one (sounds like a bug, I think it should report the problem, but I'm unsure).

To fix this, you can install an older version of Visual Studio or Windows SDK and it should work magically, or you can configure your project to use a proper TlbImp V3.5 if you have it on your machine somewhere (if you don't have it, then you *must* install something).

Here is how to modify the MsBuild project from Visual Studio:

- right click on the project node, Unload Project
- right click on the project node and Edit Project
- add the following line to your msbuild project file
- right click on the project node and Reload project
- rebuild

---

```
...
  <PropertyGroup>
    ... other properties ...
    ... <ResolveComReferenceToolPath should point to a directory that contains TLBIMP V3.5
    <ResolveComReferenceToolPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin</ResolveComReferenceToolPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

Comment: I did as you said, and changed the project to use `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\TlbImp.exe` (this exact path appears in the log for `ResolveComReference` task), and the error now changed to "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format". :(

Comment: @WGH - sounds like a 32 vs 64 bit issue.